# Reverse for 'post_share' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post_share/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

views.py

```
def post_share(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=post_id)
    sent = False

    return render(request, 'mains/post_share.html', {'post':post,'sent':sent})
```

urls.py

```
    path('post_share/<int:post_id>',views.post_share,name='post_share'),
```

show_more.html

```
  <p><a href="{% url 'mains:post_share' post.id %}">Share this post</a></p>



def __str__(self):
    return self.post_title
```

When i click on **Share this post** ( link ) **in share_more.html**  *Reverse for 'post_share' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post_share/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)$']*.

Comment: change `posts` to `post`

Comment: @minglyu I have changed it. But still error is raising.

Comment: are you sure that post_share is in the urls.py of `mains` app?

Comment: Yes, i am 100% sure. Did you find any errors ?

Comment: @Progam You are repeating the mistake, I guess last time around you ran into the same problem, Check my answer below, practice hard, read the documentation carefully, and pay more attention to the code.

Comment: Yes sir , i understand.

Comment: I completely agree with you

Answer (score 1):

Your URL expects the **post_id** kwarg;

```
 <p><a href="{% url 'mains:post_share' post_id=post.id %}">Share this post</a></p>
```

Comment: Your post.id is None, the post has been most likely deleted

Comment: The post you are referring to no longer exists, check post.id

Comment: post.id is not returning the id, check from the backend

Comment: The post context variable that you are passing to the HTML check that. Add the code of the view that is rendering <p><a href="{% url 'mains:post_share' post_id=post.id %}">Share this post</a></p>   to your question.

Comment: The view that is rendering this <p><a href="{% url 'mains:post_share' post_id=post.id %}">Share this post</a></p> HTML page, please add that view to your question

Comment: @Progam I repeat, which view is rendering show_more.html ? not post_share.html . add view to your question that is rendering show_more.html

Comment: that's fine, but how do you reach to show_more.html

Comment: There has to be a view that renders your show_more.html. Stick with my answer and debug around the show_more.html template that's all I can help you with. Your post instance seems to be None. I am ending the conversation here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225825/discussion-between-danish-wani-and-progam).

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error because of problem of "post.id" in template, it has addressed to non-existing item. Check where this line  `<p><a href="{% url 'mains:post_share' post.id %}">Share this post</a></p>` takes the `post.id` from.